# javascript onmouseout applied to div fired by children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this via google but I would have assumed it would be quite a common problem. I have a div which I have applied an onmouseout event handler to (the handler is used to roll a menu up using jquerys "slideup" function, as I would like the menu to be hidden when the mouse leaves). Problem is that the child elements of that div also cause the handler to fire (I accept that this is by design due to the nature of the bubbling event model). Now what I would like to know is what is the best way to ignore these events that are triggered by the divs children and only roll the menu up when the mouse leaves the div the event is applied to.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replys, the accepted answer ended up being the best solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is mouseenter and mouseleave.

A good example can be found at this link (they have compared both mouseenter and mouseover)

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover

A blog entry

http://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/mouse_over_out_versus_mouse

Comment: hmm i dindt know these events

Comment: Note: these are not standard W3C events. They are only natively implemented in IE... jQuery makes them work by binding regular mouseover/out events and only triggering once, when the target is the intended target.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to attempt cancelling the event bubbling or propagation. [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) has a handy section explaining how to turn off bubbling or propagation in both the models.

Since JQuery presents the [W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/events.html#Events-flow) to developers, you will not need to set the cancelbubble property. Calling stopPropagation() method will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" on the parent div instead - the child elements will not effect the "mouseleave"

```
document.getElementById('Main_Menu_Container_Div').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
// do something like your 'slideup' or what ever you want.
});
```

"Event bubbling" as it is known, is the problem - "event on element2 takes precedence. This is called event bubbling". http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Use Example:

```
<style>
.Child_Div_Button{
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border:#000 thin solid;
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px;
}


.Child_Div_Button:hover{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Parent_Div_Container" style="height:300px; width:300px; border:#333 thin solid; background-color:#D2FFFF;">
Parent Div
<div id="button_container"> 
        <div class="Child_Div_Button">
        Button 1 Child Div
        </div>

        <div class="Child_Div_Button">
        Button 2 Child Div
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

      document.getElementById('button_container').style.display = 'none';// initiate

        document.getElementById('Parent_Div_Container').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
            document.getElementById('button_container').style.display = 'block';
        });
        document.getElementById('Parent_Div_Container').addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
            document.getElementById('button_container').style.display = 'none';
        });



</script>
```

---

Seems to work in latest Firefox WITHOUT the need for JQUERY - But Chrome, IE and Safari, all seem to need the jquery library for this to work. Is that to say that mozila now fully supports the use of mouseenter and mouseleave?!?! If so .. YAY! for the browser that actually does things to help developers : )

Answer (score -1):

Simon you can check who has trigged the event using jquery Event.target property.

Answer (score -2):

No, it's not by design, you've accidentally applied your 'onmouseout' to too many divs. You only want to apply it to one.

Comment: I had only applied it to the one div and if you consider the bubbling event model I would determine that it is a by design behaviour. Have a look at the link to quirks mode in @Vineet Reynolds answer to this question.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong. You've applied it to more than 1 div.

Comment: Sorry Simon but I think *you* need to read it. I quote from it "... and both have an onClick event handler ..." So he's saying both elements have the event specified. Which is what I'm telling you. You've applied it to more than one div, so all events are fired. Of course you can cancel the general event (as others have said) but my comment is still correct.

Comment: Sorry, right site wrong article. Try this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: Simon, I won't be replying again. But please understand that you are wrong; even that article confirms it. When I test two divs one inside the other, with the outer having the 'onmouseout' the event only fires once; when I expect it to. The articles on those sites are correct, and perhaps we just have a general misunderstanding. Regardless, it's not worth further discussion.